# Angular 4 - split into specified columns based on calculation

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to make grid layout like in this [code pen](https://codepen.io/ramenhog/pen/PpEPWG) in Angular 4. Since I'm just starting with ng4 I'm a bit stuck.

The problem is that I don't want to add even items to each column. 
The idea is to check on each iteration, which column has the smallest height and add an item to it. 
I don't really know how to do that in ng4, I'm trying to do it like:

```
<div class="c-grid clearfix">
  <div
    class="c-grid-col"
    *ngFor="let col of cols"
    #colsRef
  >
    <template *ngIf="shouldAdd()">
      <app-grid-item
        *ngFor="let item of items"
      ></app-grid-item>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I can't really make it work, any tips or clues? 
Thanks